# Article title ends in te form

Tags: grammar, て-form

In this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011498691000/k10011498691000.html) the title ends with the verb in the Te-Form. Why is this or what is intended here? I don't think I have seen a sentence end with the Te-form before

> エアコンや扇風機を使う季節　火事に気を**つけて**
>
> My Translation: Its the time of year to use air conditioning and electric fans. Be careful of fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your translation is spot on.

There is absolutely no problem ending a sentence with a verb in the te-form. It is done quite commonly. This is, of course, more direct than adding ください or ね to the ending, so in conversation it has the possibility of sounding pushy, but not necessarily in a broadcast, etc.. If you are addressing someone in a higher social position who you should show deference and politeness to, this type of directness should probably be avoided.

> Polite and
>   friendly--------------------Polite-------------------------Friendly----------------Direct
>
> 気をつけてくださいね　⇒　気をつけてください　⇒　気をつけてね　⇒　気をつけて

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the politeness flow chart too

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention that any of the examples can include the politeness modifier お as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

[**気を付けて**](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B0%97%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%81%A6) is a phrase that is so commonly used, that it rarely used in anything but the -て form of the verb. (It has listings in jisho.org and my pocket dictionary.)

I understand this to be more of a public service announcement than as an article title (though it does function as both).  The feel is more of that of a friendly reminder, especially because they are talking about statistics for a portion of the article.